# Allow squid to permit skype with other restrictions for website

Tags: proxy, skype, squid

I've been trying to configure Squid proxy in my local network.

Here is a snippet of my `squid.conf` file:

```sh
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network

## Custom rules for allowing just the websites
acl AllowedSites dstdomain "c:/squid/etc/allowed.site"
#
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 2367        # Skype
#acl Safe_ports port 21     # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
#acl Safe_ports port 70     # gopher
#acl Safe_ports port 210        # wais
#acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
#acl Safe_ports port 280        # http-mgmt
#acl Safe_ports port 488        # gss-http
#acl Safe_ports port 591        # filemaker
#acl Safe_ports port 777        # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#  TAG: http_access
#   Allowing or Denying access based on defined access lists
#
#   Access to the HTTP port:
#   http_access allow|deny [!]aclname ...
#
#   NOTE on default values:
#
#   If there are no "access" lines present, the default is to deny
#   the request.
#
#   If none of the "access" lines cause a match, the default is the
#   opposite of the last line in the list.  If the last line was
#   deny, the default is allow.  Conversely, if the last line
#   is allow, the default will be deny.  For these reasons, it is a
#   good idea to have an "deny all" or "allow all" entry at the end
#   of your access lists to avoid potential confusion.
#
#Default:
# http_access deny all
#
#Recommended minimum configuration:
#
# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost

acl numeric_IPs dstdom_regex ^(([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|(\[([0-9af]+)?:([0-9af:]+)?:([0-9af]+)?\])):443
acl Skype_UA browser ^skype^

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
# Deny requests to unknown ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports
# Deny CONNECT to other than SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
#
# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost
#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow AllowedSites
http_access allow CONNECT localnet numeric_IPs Skype_UA
http_access deny !AllowedSites

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all
```

Now, the problem here is, that when I allow skype, it starts allowing ALL websites.

I need a way by which I can restrict the websites just to the `allowed.site` file domains, which contains a list of allowed sites.

Also, I need to block port 443, but allow that same port for Skype.

Please guide me on how this can be possible.

Thanks,